# primefaces dataexporter prints html and EL expressions structure not data in table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to print a simple report with data exporter, but what I got print is the structure not the data, same issue with any format (xsl,csv,pdf). The number of rows I got and the name columns is correct, except data in table.

The browser throws this warning:
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "http://localhost:8081/prueba2/faces/views/usrManagement.xhtml".

here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="userTable" 
      value="#{userManagementBean.lazyModel}"
      var="user" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros"
      tableStyle="table-layout:auto;" reflow="true"
      paginator="true" rows="5" lazy="true"
      paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown}{FirstPageLink}
                         {PreviousPageLink}{PageLinks}
                         {NextPageLink}{LastPageLink}">                      

      <f:facet name="header">
        Usuarios
      </f:facet>
      <p:column exportable="false">
         <f:facet name="header">Acciones</f:facet>

         <p:commandLink class="btn-floating
                 waves-effect waves-light blue"
                 action="#{userManagementBean.chosenUsr(user)}"
                 onsuccess="$('#CRUDModal').modal('open');"
                 update="modalForm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>  
        </p:commandLink>               
     </p:column>
     <p:column>
       <f:facet name="header">Clave de usuario</f:facet>
          #{user.aliasVarc}
     </p:column>

     <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Número de empleado</f:facet>
          #{user.codEmployeeInt}
     </p:column>

     <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Nombre</f:facet>
          #{user.nameVarc}
     </p:column>

     <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">A paterno</f:facet>
          #{user.lastNameVarc}
     </p:column>
     <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Activo</f:facet> 
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{user.isActiveBit}" />
        <label></label>

     </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -1px;">
<div class="fixed-action-btn ">
<a class="btn-floating btn-large amber accent-3">
  <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
</a>
<ul>
  <li><a class="btn-floating blue lighten-3"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o">
</i></a></li>
  <li><a class="btn-floating red darken-1"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
</a></li>

<li>
   <h:commandLink class="btn-floating green darken-3">
   <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="userTable" fileName="reporte" 
          pageOnly="false" />
      <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o">
      </i></h:commandLink>
  </li>

  <li><p:commandLink class="btn-floating  blue waves-effect waves-light"
                     action="#{userManagementBean.newUser()}"
                     onsuccess="$('#CRUDModal').modal('open');"
                     update="modalForm">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </p:commandLink></li>

</ul>
</div>          
</div>
```

here is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserManagementBean implements Serializable{
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String userName;
private List<Usrs> liUsrs;
private Usrs selectedUsr;
private boolean deleteBtnRendered;
private LazyDataModel<Usrs> lazyModel;
private HashMap<String,Object> params;
private int paginator;




@PostConstruct
public void initMethod() {

    selectedUsr = new Usrs();
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public List<Usrs> getLiUsrs() {
    return liUsrs;
}

public void setLiUsrs(List<Usrs> liUsrs) {
    this.liUsrs = liUsrs;
}

public Usrs getSelectedUsr() {
    return selectedUsr;
}

public void setSelectedUsr(Usrs selectedUsr) {
    this.selectedUsr = selectedUsr;
    System.out.println("alias"+selectedUsr.getAliasVarc());
}

public boolean isDeleteBtnRendered() {
    return deleteBtnRendered;
}

public void setDeleteBtnRendered(boolean deleteBtnRendered) {
    this.deleteBtnRendered = deleteBtnRendered;
}

public LazyDataModel<Usrs> getLazyModel() {

    return lazyModel;
}

public int getPaginator() {
    return paginator;
}

public void setPaginator(int paginator) {
    this.paginator = paginator;
}

public void chosenUsr(Usrs selected){
    selectedUsr = selected;
    deleteBtnRendered = true;
}

public void callSearchProcess(){
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("aliasVarc", userName);

    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                           getViewRoot().
                           findComponent("searchForm:userTable");
    dataTable.reset(); 
    lazyModel = new LazyUserList(params);
}

public void callInUpProcess(){
    new UserManagementController(this).mergeUser();
    selectedUsr = new Usrs();
}
public void callDeleteProcess(){
    new UserManagementController(this).deleteUser();
    selectedUsr = new Usrs();
}
public void newUser(){
     selectedUsr = new Usrs();
     deleteBtnRendered = false;
}
}
```

and this is the result
[result in pdf format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y7tp.png)

[csv format][2]

Answer (score 5):

The PF dataexporter only knows how to export simple 'data' things. It is not an html exporter. So that `<label>` does not work is 'by design'. Regarding the other EL, you need to use them like this:

```
<h:outputText value=" #{user.lastNameVarc}" />
```

Then it will work for sure

Comment: Correct answer, I was going to post the same, but spent too much time testing to be sure. :(